# How add new date formats to work in 'tpope/vim-speeddating' vim plugin?

Tags: vimrc

In vim plugin 'tpope/vim-speeddating', it support wide variaty of date formats. e.g.

```
 %Y-%m-%d%[ T_-]%H:%M             2019-08-04 07:42
 %Y-%m-%d                         2019-08-04
```

But how to add my custom data formats, e.g.

```
 %Y/%m/%d                         2019/08/04
 %Y/%m                            2019/08
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation: (`help speeddating`)

> One can use the `:SpeedDatingFormat` command to list, add, and remove formats. A good place to place custom formats is in `.vim/after/plugin/speeddating.vim`

For the formats you listed:

```
SpeedDatingFormat %Y/%m/%d
SpeedDatingFormat %Y/%m
```

Answer (score 0):

Write these lines in your ~/.vimrc

```
au BufEnter * :SpeedDatingFormat %Y/%m/%d
au BufEnter * :SpeedDatingFormat %Y/%m
```

Comment: I think using the `VimEnter` autocmd should work as well? That way it won't be re-run every time you enter a buffer, which probably isn't needed (I think?)